# Add additional login field in spring boot oauth2 Authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have implemented oauth2 server in spring boot and it uses UserDetailsService where it override one method loadUserByUsername. I want other additional field for example username, password and phonenumber in login form.

My WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


}
```

My Authorization Server

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer(){
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(SecurityConstant.PRIVATE_KEY);
        converter.setVerifierKey(SecurityConstant.PUBLIC_KEY);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(){
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oAuthClientPasswordEncoder;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(oAuthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer());
    }
}
```

To be honest i don't know where to do what?

Comment: What is the purpose of having phoneNumber when doing OAuth Authentication?

Comment: Is it solved your problem

Comment: @ShahidNeermunda I did other way. I created new endpoint /login where I can post model which includes username, password and phone number. From there I used RestTemplate and call oauth2 endpoint for authentication purpose and other data I just wanted to store it to database which is done after check if authenticated or not